# App Name was overrided by library?

Tags: android, android-studio

I added a **library** into my project in **android studio**
But my **app name** was changed into the library's name
How to change it back without removing the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for most situations you can just delete the **app_name** string of the lib,or you can  modify your app module's string.xml  **app_name** to a unique name and don't forget to change the reference in the menifest file

Comment: I use gradle to add library, so it is not possible to change library's name

Comment: i did give you 2 choices...modify your app module's string.xml  will do  also @Waylan Punch

Answer (score 0):

After remove the gradle config, I add library from the folder, and change the app name.